# HTTP Error 403.14 - Issue when hosting site on IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an `MVC 4` small application. My app is working fine when i am running it on `Localhost`. But when i a hosting the site on `IIS 7.0,` it is giving me following error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

The solution for the above issue is to enable the directory browsing (this is what i found on Internet). But i think this is not the solution. The reason is after enabling the director browsing, i am getting another error:

```
HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.
```

I have tried to find the solution for the above problem. It says that allow your `.cs` file on application `host.config`. But after doing the suggested change, still it is giving me some error.

Does anyone know what could be the exact problem?

Comment: Is MVC installed on the remote server?

Comment: check your `default` `MapRoute` in `RegisterRoutes` of `Global.asax.cs` file. Set the controller and action to correct start up action.

Comment: yes mVC is installed. Actually IIS is present on my local machine only.

Comment: @viki could you please elaborate a little more. I mean i have proper route set up, as it is working in asp.net development web server. The problem occurs when i host the site on IIS7.0

Comment: The problem solved by adding one line in web.config
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in CMD : 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

I was facing similar issue and this worked for me.